# Sway Gives XDG_RUNTIME_DIR Error

Tags: debian, wayland, sway

*Please forgive me if I make a mistake; this is my first time asking.*

I am on Debian 12. I have tried installing Sway, but it throws an error:

```
~$ sudo sway
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set in the environment. Aborting.
```

However, bash confirms that $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is set to `/home/lyran/.xdgrd` (and yes, I have added the `export` command to my bash profile).

### What I've Tried

I could not find any documentation on the error in Debian. So, I tried [a solution I found for Arch.](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/7202) After installing and starting/enabling `seatd`, adding myself to the `seat` group, and restarting, I still get the same error. I could find no other solutions to it.

Answer (score 0):

don't run sway with sudo, instead run sway with a display manager instead ie lightdm